# oData filter on related EntityType

Tags: odata

Consuming Northwind v2 oData service, for learning purposes, I run into the following issue: the `Employees` entity is related to the `Orders` entity. Using expand parameter I can get all related `Orders`. Here I want to use a filter to filter on, let's say, `CustomerID`. I have been trying to do something like this following different documentations but could make this work:

`https://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Employees?$expand=Orders&$filter=Orders/CustomerID eq 'ERNSH'`

We get following error: *No property 'CustomerID' exists in type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1[[ODataWeb.Northwind.Model.Order, ODataWeb, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69c3241e6f0468ca]]*

CustomerID should exist on the `Order` entity as this call gives back expected results:

```
https://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders?$filter%20=CustomerID%20eq%20%27ERNSH%27
```

How do you apply a filter on the nested entityType?

Answer (score 0):

if `Orders` is a collection you can use `any` in the filter query.

```
https://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Employees?$expand=Orders&$filter=Orders/any(c:c/CustomerID eq 'ERNSH')
```

Other option is to use `filter` inside the `expand`

```
https://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Employees?$expand=Orders($filter=CustomerID eq 'ERNSH')
```

Comment: Orders are a collection as are Employees. Unfortunately, your first example gives following error: 

No property 'any' exists in type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1[[ODataWeb.Northwind.Model.Order, ODataWeb, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69c3241e6f0468ca]]' at position 7.

and your second - Syntax error at position 7.

Comment: @TomášTomHaverla Are there any reasons why you are using V2? Queries do not fail for V4

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. The problem is that I have another private v2 oData service and it is a constraint to use v2. That is why I am testing the same scope on the Northwind v2 data. I believe there must be a way to apply a filter on an expanded collection but I couldn't make it work. If it is not possible with v2 I will have to make separate calls instead of using expand and filter.